# Too few arguments to function Admin::edit(),

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm new in codeigniter and php,
and am trying to create crud (update)
how to solve this?
thanks in advance

Model :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Role_model extends CI_Model
{

    public function DeleteRole($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('user_role');
    }

    public function GetId($id)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where('user_role', ['id' => $id])->row_array();
    }


    public function EditRole()
    {
        $data = [

            "role" => $this->input->post('role' , true)
        ];

        $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'));
        $this->db->update('user_role', $data);
    }




}
```

controller :

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        is_logged_in();
        $this->load->model('Role_model');
    }

public function edit($id)
{
    $data['title'] = 'Role';
    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();
    $data['user_role'] = $this->Role_model->GetId($id);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('role', 'Role', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
        $this->Role_model->EditRole();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Role Edited!</div>');
        redirect('admin/role');
    } 
}
```

view :

```
<div class="card-body">
    <?= $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>
    <form action="<?= base_url('admin/edit/');?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $user_role['id']; ?>">
        <div class="form-group text-gray-900">
            <label for="role">Edit Role</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="role" name="Role" value="<?= $user_role['role']; ?>">
            <?= form_error('role', ' <small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
        </div>
</div>
```

and it display like this

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
> Type: ArgumentCountError
>
> Message: Too few arguments to function Admin::edit(), 0 passed in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\KingflowWP2\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain to you.

Edit function needs one parameter (i.e. `id`). In your form, you are submitting the form without `id`.

You just need to add the `id` at the end of the URL like below.  Suppose `id` is 2 then you have to add 2.

```
base_url('admin/edit/2')

<form action="<?= base_url('admin/edit/2');?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only passing $id in

```
$this->usermodel->Role_model($get['id']);
```

Comment: i dont understand what u mean ..
then how to solve it ?

Comment: @DwiGigih, Check your controller line no. 5

Comment: $data['user_role'] = $this->Role_model->GetId($id); this ?

Comment: what is GetId and please pass string not variable - id

Comment: public function GetId($id)
 {
  return $this->db->get_where('user_role', ['id' => $id])->row_array();
 }

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your function if you want to post value in hidden input. Oner more thing you have to use default argument if you are not sure about the data is present or not. Always check step by step that data is present or not than do anything.

Write echo here so you get the value in hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $user_role['id']; ?>">
```

After that change in the function:

```
public function edit()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $data['title'] = 'Role';
    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();
    if(!empty($id)):
        $data['user_role'] = $this->Role_model->GetId($id);
    else:
        //some error message 
    endif;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('role', 'Role', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
        $this->Role_model->EditRole();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Role Edited!</div>');
        redirect('admin/role');
    } 
}
```

Comment: still error ,
An Error Was Encountered
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: user_role

Filename: admin/edit.php

Line Number: 18

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\KingflowWP2\application\views\admin\edit.php
Line: 18
Function: _error_handler

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $user_role['id']; ?>">`

Comment: Please check $user_role first. Is it empty or have value?